# Why does META-INF keep coming back?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to use the mod I've installed. I have Forge installed and I have ended the task "Java", but everytime I delete META-INF it keeps coming back everytime I open the Minecraft Launcher 1.2.1. But I know YouTubers have their mods working fine on 1.6! Someone please tell me the answer to this, it's very annoying. Just to confirm, it regenerates when I try to play Minecraft. I already deleted the entire file, so why does it keep coming back!?

Comment: When you launch minecraft after installing the mods and deleting meta-Inf, does it still have forge and/or the mod installed?

Comment: The new launcher (used for 1.6 and up) requires a few extra steps to mod; see the question I just linked.

Comment: @Jonny Yeah it has the profile "Forge" and it has Forge on my Minecraft menu too, but it crashes if the MutantCreatures folder in in the mods folder, which makes me think META-INF is responsible. I think it's still there because my Minecraft keeps updating?

Comment: @Billy Mailman Yeah that doesn't work :\